# VS 2015 Web Application Identity Model Access Custom Data

Tags: visual-studio-2015, web-applications, asp.net-identity

So, I've been working on a web application in vs 2015, this is a non MVC project but evidently has components to enable MVC.

I'm having a lot of issues navigating around this platform because most of the resources out there, even some of the links embedded within the class code of the automatically generated resources when you create a project, are referencing older resources with entirely different structures.

In my project, I've successfully added additional user profile data, like FirstName and LastName etc.

```
var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            var signInManager = Context.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = Email.Text, Email = Email.Text, FirstName = FirstName.Text, LastName = LastName.Text, StreetNumber = Convert.ToInt32(StreetNumber.Text), StreetName = StreetName.Text };
```

in the registration form and the data is writing to the database, I'd like to be able to

1. Evaluate if user is logged in (clear example of how to do that in the project already)
2. get the the users custom data ex First Name from the identity model dB.

Every resource I've searched on references MVC projects and having and AccountViewModel which my project doesn't have because I didn't choose MVC when creating my project.  This is entirely strange as well because I didn't select MVC.

I am hoping someone could point me to some resources on how to work with regular ol' web app (non-mvc) projects.

This is everything the project provided plus I added a couple classes and folders.

[image]

This is the database, I've modified it using the nuget package manager migrations to add the custom fields. like FirstName, LastName, StreetNumber etc.

[image: Database Table]

And Here's the data that was successfully input into the database at registration.[image]

This is all fine a great, plenty of resources that explain how to get the data into the database, but haven't found anything on how to use the data. I would greatly appreciate any assistance finding current resources.

Answer (score 0):

I found a great article (non-microsoft.. go figure) on how to access identity model custom data, it was written for vs2013 but its valid for vs2015 because I am now able to access my custom field data for my users in the identity model framework.

[Customize User's Profile in ASP.NET Identity System](http://www.itorian.com/2013/11/customize-users-profile-in-aspnet.html)

Microsoft walks you thought how to create custom data in the database but doesn't discuss BOO on how to access it once the data is in there.  This article clearly describes how to do that.

Required dependencies

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
```

Then the code with just an example of my label on the page called "uname"

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        var LoggedOnUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        uname.Text = LoggedOnUser.FirstName;
    }
```

This in-short is pretty much all you really need in the code-behind to reference your custom data.